# Dropdownlist with datasource set and empty value?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

Is there a quick way to add a blank value to a drop down list for a winforms application?  Some of my dropdowns are bound to lists of objects and some are bound to datarows from a datatable.  Since I am setting the datasource property, I can't just add one through code.  Is there any quick way of getting a blank value added or will I have to do it manually for each drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a DataRow with empty values to your datatable programatically,

Comment: That's what I figured.  But I wasn't sure if there was a quick four-liner that would just add a blank object to the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I've used to do a blank entry before enum values. Obviously this won't work for more complex binding scenarios.

```
combo1.DataSource = (new object[] { null }
                        .Concat(Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnumType)).Cast<object>()))
                            .ToList();
```